# Is it possible to invoke code for all Catch blocks without adding it manually?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a custom exception class that will wrap around any other exception that is thrown.  This way I will always know the exception was handled and all other methods and layers will know to just pass the exception up to the UI.  However, when an exception is first thrown I want to the exact same thing everytime.

```
    catch (TestWebException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);

        var x = new TestWebException(ex.Message);
        x.SourceException = ex;
        throw x;
    }
```

Is there a mechanism in place to inject this logic into every catch block or call it by default?  You'll notice there is no custom information that I need to add or edit, this code can run for every base exception in the entire application.

Comment: How is this different from registering an event handler to unhandled events for an AppDomain? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you may consider injecting aspects into your application.  IOC containers like Unity facilitate aspect oriented programming (AOP).

Comment: Not sure I understand. It seems like you are trying to intercept exceptions at every layer only to perform logging.  Why not just let the exception go unhandled all the way up to the UI, and let it take care of logging it?  That way you don't need the custom exception wrapping logic at all.  Otherwise, it sounds like you will need a bunch of `try-catch` blocks all over the place and at every layer. Doesn't sound pleasant.

Comment: @sstan The simplicity of that is slapping me in the face.  Is such a simple solution acceptable?  It makes sense, but feels weird.  I'm scared.

Comment: That's the usual way to do it, and it has many advantages.  If anything, one very compelling reason to let the exception go unhandled until the very last second (UI layer) before you log it: so that you get a meaningful and complete stack trace.  With the solution you were thinking, the logged exception's stack trace would be incomplete.  It would be missing the call stack between the UI and the point of logging.  That would make debugging the exception very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. you will need to register exceptionfilterattribute in the FilterConfig.cs

your FilterConfig.cs should be like below:

```
    public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new TestWebExceptionFilterAttribute()); // Custom Exception & Log Handling
    }
}
```

And the class TestWebExceptionFilterAttribute should be as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ITFort.TestWeb.Models.DBFirst.Authorization;
namespace ITFort.TestWeb.Filters
{
    public class TestWebExceptionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        using (TestWebAuthorizationEntities db = new TestWebAuthorizationEntities())
        {
            ExceptionDatabaseTable exception = new ExceptionDatabaseTable;
            exception.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            exception.Controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            exception.Action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            exception.Message = filterContext.Exception.Message;
            exception.StackTrace = filterContext.Exception.StackTrace;
            exception.ErrorDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(exception).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: it works only if your exception is not handled. 
@AdamHeeg do you just want to log and let the exception bubble or do you want to be able to handle it later?

Comment: i want to let it bubble up to the UI where the front end developers would decide how to interact with the user.  The only thing we would do on the entire back end would be to log it.  I'm only doing a proof of concept right now, things could change.

Comment: ok so just throw the exception right after saving it. after db.savechanges(); write this: throw filterContext.Exception;

Comment: Did he mention ASP MVC?

Comment: is this answer related to a web framework?  I'm stuggling finding relevant information on the FilterConfiguration class.  I am using a asp.net web form for testing purposes on the front end, but the code will be used in the logic and data layer (single layer for us).

Comment: the answer is related to asp.net mvc framework. i am using this implementation in asp.net mvc web applications. TestWebAuthorizationEntities  will be in your datalayer and that you can give access to front end developer.